# Image should fit canvas borders on zooming in/out

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a canvas with image in it. The image is re-sizable and draggable. 
I am trying to implement the logic that you can see in mobile gallery apps (e.g. Google Photos), when the image cannot be dragged outside the viewport. 
I'm stacked on the scale: when the image is zoomed in and then zoomed out, it does not fit the borders any more.

Now I'm using such validation< but it's not really successfull:

```
if (backgoundImage.height > backgoundImage.width) {
        if (canvas.height * scaleValue * factor < canvas.clientHeight) {
            factor = canvas.clientHeight / (canvas.height * scaleValue)
        }
    } else {
        if (canvas.width * scaleValue * factor < canvas.clientWidth) {
            factor = canvas.clientWidth / (canvas.width * scaleValue)
        }
    }
```

I know it's quite pure explanation of what's happening, so here's the demo:

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Cuddles/gy31xrka/3/)

Can someone help with advice how I can fit the borders all the time using once I've used zoom?

Comment: Keep the top-left corner always negative or zero at max.

Comment: @Teemu that's not the right approach. try to zoom in/out any image in your gallery app on your phone - corners can get negative coords while the size of the image allows to do it. If I keep the corner with some static number coords, it will make the zooming relative not the the point where the cursor at, but at the static point I'm using

Comment: But .. but ... that's what I've just said, "_keep ... always negative_" i.e. you should never allow top-left corner values exceed zero.

Comment: @Teemu oh, guess I've misunderstood you. ok, will give it a try, thanks)

Comment: It's possible, that I haven't fully understood your question either = ).